# My Django/Python Code is Not Rendering HTML <a> Tag in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want something similar to Twitter mentions that are turned into links but it is not working.
If we assume we have `message` = 'Do not forget to come with the Python book, @friend'

```
#function to convert @mentions to links
def mentions(message, username):
    this_user_handle = reverse('mysite:profile', args=[username])
    new_message = re.sub(r'(@\w+)', r"<a href= '#'>\g<0></a>", message)
    new_message.replace('#', this_user_handle)
    return new_message
```

`mentions(message, 'yax')` returns `Do not forget to come with the Python book, <a href= '#'>@friend</a>'`.
The `#` is not replaced and the `new_message` still displays as is in HTML page:

```
<p class= 'Post'>
    {{ new_message|linebreaksbr}}
</p>
```

This displays this:

```
Do not forget to come with the Python book, <a href= '#'>@friend</a>'
```

Instead of:

Do not forget to come with the Python book, [@friend](http://example.com/)

How do I get around this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace returns a new string.

```
new_message = new_message.replace("#", "...")
```

Also Django automatically escapes HTML in templates, to disable it use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) filter.

Answer (score 1):

The content is being [automatically escaped](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping) to prevent things like script injection. Use the `|safe` filter is you're certain that it can't contain anything nasty.

Comment: Anything nasty? Can you enlighten me more on that? Links can do.

Comment: User handler or message containing `<script>alert("I'm nasty");</script>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use kwargs instead of args:

```
reverse('profile', kwargs={'user_name': username})
```

You should replace the href='' by href="" to avoid mixing things you don't want to mix (you would need to replace that in several places tho).